# Android dropdown from a Image Button

Tags: java, android, spinner, imagebutton

I am trying to create a dropdown (like a spinner) which happens when you click on a imagebutton. I've tried doing this through a spinner with a background image, but it stretches the button as wide as the largest option in the dropdown menu. I want the button to always be a fixed, small size (smaller than some options in the menu)

What is the easiest way to do this, and how would i implement it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the menu items width/height to some specific constant value? If you don't like the Spinner logic, you might want to check this article about quick action dialogs: http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Comment: Yh that works, hadn't thought of that